# How to modify data received from fetch Request in React

Tags: reactjs, fetch

The question is how to modify data received from fetch Request in React?

1)I get the result of a fetch request and put in into state
2)To work with the data I need to modify it (add an ID and a boolean to each item of the array inside one of the objects of the coming array.

I tried the following way, but it doesn't work:

````
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=10&difficulty=easy&type=multiple"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data.map(question => ({
        ...question,
        incorrect_answers: question.incorrect_answers.map(answer => {...answer, isSelected: false})
      })));
  }, []); ```
````

Comment: can you post the expected result after modifying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` is a object so you can't map over it. The data object has a property `results` which contains the array of questions.

```js
data.results.map((question) => ({ ... })
```

Then the first time you correctly ***surround*** the object you return with `()` but when you `map` over the `incorrect_answers` you don't.

```js
incorrect_answers: question.incorrect_answers.map((answer) => ({
  ...answer,
  isSelected: false,
}));
```

Full code

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(
    "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=10&difficulty=easy&type=multiple"
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) =>
      data.results.map((question) => ({
        ...question,
        incorrect_answers: question.incorrect_answers.map((answer) => ({
          answer,
          isSelected: false,
        })),
      }));
    );
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, but inside of ```incorrect_answers```  I have a string, not an object, I need to modify the string to be the value ```answer``` of a key of a new created object.

Comment: I updated my answer to not use the **spread operator** on the `answer` value, now `incorrect_answer` will be a array of object with the props `answer` and `isSelected`. Could explain what you mean by *he value answer of a key of a new created object*?

Comment: I mean that I need to change ```answer``` from string to object, because at the moment it's a string, maybe that's why the code isn't working...

Comment: The code's working, thanks a lot for your help. Problem solved:)